# As a sentinel how to kill a guardian

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I counter enemies with Riot Shields in Mass Effect 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51883/how-can-i-counter-enemies-with-riot-shields-in-mass-effect-3)

The playstyle is mostly rushing with the shotgun, and also using melee attacks. Now the trouble is with the guardians (the cerberus guys with the shields). Rushing just doesn't work, and aiming on their feet with a shotgun or trying to run around them doesn't work either. The trouble is their shield. I can use the push power on them and then try to get in a melee attack but they recover too fast to use the power melee attack.

Is there a way to take their shield away?

Edit: to be clear this is close combat only, a sentinel doesn't have pull, or i don't use the sniper rifle.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question into a more succinct, readable format. Leave out the extraneous, casual verbiage and get to the point of your question(s).

Comment: @Fabian I don't have the power pull, nor do i use a sniper rifle... I am talking about close combat

Comment: @Lyrion **don't engage a Guardian in frontal close combat**. Sneak around and hit him from behind, learn to use a heavy pistol, or rely on your companions (in single player) or teammates (in MP) to deal with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for the Sentinel, who has access to Throw - this will stun the Guardian for a while, giving you a window of opportunity to shoot at him. Using Pull and Singularity are better though - the former removes the shield while the latter will hang him in mid air.

Answer (score 1):

There are a slew of possible tactics to use against guardians. A few possibilities:

- Knock him off his feet with powers
- Attack from behind using your squad mates to flank
- Use the "pull" power to pry the shield out of his hands
- Use the "stasis" power to stun him and cause him to drop his shield
- Use the M-98 Widow weapon's anti-material rounds to go through the shield

Take a look at this wiki page for even more methods: [LINK](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian).

Answer (score 0):

Liara's Singularity throws them up in the air and makes their shield useless. I like having her around for exactly that purpose.